# Android java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method

Tags: java, android, httpclient, google-forms, http-request

***I would like to send a post request to send data to my worksheet by Google Form***

I use Android Studio, in my android project I have an error when I try to execute `DefaultHttpClient` object I get :

> --------- beginning of crash
>   10-26 16:19:08.749  21824-22874/mypackage E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1553
>       Process: mypackage, PID: 21824
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse; in class Lorg/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

the error is reported to the line: `response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);`

**I use httpclient-4.5.1.jar library**

*minSDK: API 15: Android 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich)*

I don't know how to fix this! Please Help Me!

Comment: you might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1617056/706833, maybe can help you ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext: method <init>()V not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617042/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-http-protocol-basichttpcontext-method)

Comment: can you share your target sdk ?

Comment: @dex where can I find it in Androii Studio???

Comment: target SDK is what android version you are targeting and it is defined inside Android Manifest , if you haven't defined any thing then min SDK is your target SDK

Comment: @dex In my AndroidManifest I don't define anything target SDK

Comment: @mc_marad what is minSDK ?

Comment: @dex API 15: Android 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93388/discussion-between-dex-and-mc-marad).

Answer (score 11):

in build.gradle android section put this code

**useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'**

Comment: grt answer, i ws stuck @Din Islam Milon

Comment: Simple but helpful answer :)